# Jekyll Contentful, how to hide api key from config file?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions, contentful

Jekyll contentful plugin is configured in the config.yml file. But if I publish the repo on a public github repository, the api key will be available for anyone to use it. 
How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CloudCannon (CMS for Jekyll) as an alternative. CloudCannon does not require an API key, supports Github and allows you to use a private repo. The free account should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no possible way to do that.

Please open an issue on GitHub and we'll add that feature as soon as we can.

Else, as a workaround, you can omit your `config.yml` file from being pushed if you're not using it for GitHub Pages, by adding it to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: I need my config file in the repo because I'm deploying with netlify. What I'm doing currently is pasting the snippet only when I need to update data, because I'm just testing it out. But that wouldn't be sustainable. I guess the best way for now is a private repo. Thanks for the answer.